# Excel formula using countif on sample data

Tags: excel, count, formula, countif

We want to find out how many Data00_A_Up and Data00_B_Up is there , we are not concerned about the digit which comes after A and B like A1,A2,B1,B2 and all. For all Data, that is Data00,Data01,...so on we need to find out how many Data_A_Up and Data_B_Up is there using formula in excel. I came up with this formula

```
=COUNTIF(A1:C10,"Data00_A?_Up")
```

this will give total A_Up for Data00. Similarly

```
=COUNTIF(A1:C10,"Data01_B?_Up")
```

this will give total number of B_Up for Data01.
Each time we have to edit this formula to Data01,Data02,etc. So is there any one formula to calculate everything at once.

***Dataset***
[image]

Comment: What is your excel version?

Comment: 2019 microsoft office version

Comment: Could you please explain the formula

Answer (score 0):

With Microsoft 365 you may try below formula to count `Up` for Data00, Data01...

```
=LET(x,UNIQUE(LEFT(A1:A10,SEARCH("_",A1:A10)-1)),CHOOSE({1,2},x,COUNTIFS(A1:A10,x&"*",A1:A10,"*Up")))
```

If you need to distinguish A and B then could try-

```
=LET(x,UNIQUE(LEFT(A1:A10,8)),CHOOSE({1,2},x,COUNTIFS(A1:A10,x&"*",A1:A10,"*Up")))
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain this formula?